# React Hightlight.js "TypeError: #<NodeList> is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, markdown

To highlight code in a component that is loaded asynchronously, use hightlight.js as shown in the following code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import marked from 'marked';
import { highlightBlock } from 'highlight.js';

class MarkdownContent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { _md } = this;
        let blocks = _md.querySelectorAll('pre code');
        Array.prototype.forEach(blocks, block => highlightBlock(block));
    }

    render() {
        const { content } = this.props;
        let html = marked(content).replace(
            /<a(.*?)href="http/g,
            '<a$1target="_blank" href="http'
        );
        return (
            <div
                ref={el => (this._md = el)}
                className="md-content"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }}
            />
        );
    }
}

MarkdownContent.propTypes = { content: PropTypes.string };
MarkdownContent.defaultProps = { content: '' };
export default MarkdownContent;
```

However, react prints the following error: This method works well in jquery or vuejs, but why?

> TypeError: # is not a function
>       MarkdownContent.componentDidMount
>       C:/mygit/blog/frontend/src/Common/Markdown/MarkdownContent.js:10
>          7 |    componentDidMount() {
>          8 |        const { _md } = this;
>          9 |        let blocks = _md.querySelectorAll('pre code');
>
> > 10 |        Array.prototype.forEach(blocks, block => highlightBlock(block));
> >           11 |    }
> >           12 | 
> >           13 |    render() {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` doesn't return an `Array`, it returns a `NodeList`. If you create an `Array` from that `NodeList`, your code will work fine.

Replace line 10 with this:

```
Array.from(blocks).forEach(block => highlightBlock(block));
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you want to make your code even more terse, you can omit the lamba wrapper function and just pass `highlightBlock` directly to forEach.

Comment: It certainly seems reasonable. .forEach(highlightBlock);